# how to calculate the time required by a java application to draw ui?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I want to measure the response time of user interface developed in Java swing.  The application can be a simple window containing some buttons, frames and pictures. I am not a Java geek so need an idea to start in this direction.

How can we calculate the time taken by a Java application to draw user interface developed using swing?

Comment: How do you define "draw UI"?

Comment: the simplest way would to to insert timestamps into your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check with this stuff and make the log for you to analyse

```
startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

logString.append(""+(endTime - startTime));
```